# Can C-like function call syntax be easily achieved for particular function names?

Tags: syntax, operators

I'm trying to use Mathematica as a tool to prove that some C code is equivalent to another (up to roundoff errors). For this I need to somehow paste C expressions like `sqrt(sqr(x)+y*z)`. I.e. the expressions that contain function calls.

There's a set of functions I know beforehand, and I would like to make it possible to use them as some objects which, on being multiplied on the right by something, result in applying functions instead of multiplication. I.e. I need to make the above expression automatically convert to `Sqrt[square[x]+y z]`.

How can I achieve this? Note: I'm not looking for a complete C-to-Wolfram translator. Only this particular function-call syntax with particular function names.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a handy package, [Notation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/Notation/guide/NotationPackage.html), built-in to Mathematica. With it, we can do the following:

```
Needs["Notation`"]

Notation[ParsedBoxWrapper[RowBox[{"sqrt", RowBox[{"(", "x_", ")"}]}]]
         ⟹
         ParsedBoxWrapper[SqrtBox["x_"]]]

Notation[ParsedBoxWrapper[RowBox[{"sqr",  RowBox[{"(", "x_", ")"}]}]]
         ⟹
         ParsedBoxWrapper[SuperscriptBox["x_", "2"]]]
```

In the Mathematica Notebook interface, it looks like this (after `` Needs["Notation`"] `` has been executed, and then you selected the `Notation[...]` and pressed <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>):

[image: screenshot]

After entering this code, we can simply do

```
d = sqrt(sqr(a)+2*a*R)
```

and get our output

> Sqrt[a^2 + 2 a R]

Answer (score 4):

Maybe you can use the fact that [`TraditionalForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TraditionalForm) by default interprets parentheses as function calls:

```
fromCString[s_String] := ReplaceAll[
    ToExpression[s, TraditionalForm, Defer],
    {
        sqrt -> Sqrt,
        sqr -> square
    }
]
```

Then:

```
fromCString["sqrt(sqr(x)+y*z)"]
```

> Sqrt[square[x] + y z]